# Accessing object of type info_data which has been invalidated or deleted realm in react native

Tags: react-native, realm

I am having this error "Accessing object which has been invalidated or deleted",
i have gone through the solutions online but still cant find a solution to fix it, 
see code below

```js
deleteData(t_id) {
realm.write(() => {
            if (realm.objects('track_info').filtered('track_id =' + t_id).length > 0) {
                realm.delete(realm.objects('track_info').filtered('track_id =' + t_id));
                console.warn("REcord deleted");

               
                Alert.alert(
                    'Successes', 'deleted');
            } else {
               Alert.alert(
                   'Error', 'Record not found, or has been deleted already');
            }

         


        });

    }
```

and the call to the function

```
<TouchableOpacity style={[styles.BtnSuccess,
                        { flex: 2, flexDirection: 'row' }]} onPress={this.deleteData(this.state.t_id)}>
                            <Text style={[styles.btnText, { flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', alignContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'center' }]}>Submit</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Please can someine help me out on how to resolved this please.......

Answer (score 0):

Try to retrieve the object first, and check if the object is valid or not then only perform the deletion.

```
var obj = realm.objects('track_info').filtered('track_id =' + t_id)
if(obj.isValid())
 // perform deletion
else
 // alert message
```